# Plaster repair mistake fixing hairline cracks

Tags: repair, painting, plaster, uk

I have some walls (brick and plaster) with some plaster in poor condition. Mainly hairline cracks.

I dug out the hairline cracks to a V shape groove and filled them with a repair compound. However, I made the mistake of skimming them flat with a float while still wet. Subsequently, the repair compound seems to have shrunk back a tiny amount into the groove. When painted, the paint finish is not dead flat - you can see channels the width of the V through two coats of paint. Very shallow, but visible.

What's the best way to proceed? Dig the cracks out and start again? Skim over the top and sand flat? Apply more paint and rub down? Give up on the repair and have all the plaster hacked off the walls and replaster?

Comment: I think the word skim denotes removing, not adding more plaster. Also leave a comment for Aloysius if his answer is not adequate.

Answer (score 1):

You had it right with "skim over the top and sand flat". The only thing you want to do is scuff the paint gently with sandpaper to help the joint compound bite.